# How should I start X after ssh'ing into a remote box?

Tags: linux, ssh, x11, clipboard

I am trying to syncronize my clipboard with a remote machine using `XQuartz` and `xsel`. It works, but only after I run an X windows program:

connecting from Mac OS X with Quartz running and the pasteboard options selected:

http://img41.imageshack.us/img41/6913/picturehsv.png

```
ssh user@host -X
ls | xsel -b

(local clipboard is not affected)

xeyes

(close xeyes)

ls | xcel -b

(now local system's clipboard works as you would expect)
```

it seems that starting any x program, like `xeyes` or `gvim` somehow completes the connection.

`xsel` has an option to specify display - would that affect thing?

I don't have `startx` or `xinit` installed (and I don't really want to install those) and this works fine after starting one of these x programs.

I also installed `xsm` to try and debug or figure out the display name, but running it just tells me:

```
sh: iceauth: not found
sh: twm: not found
sh: xterm: not found
smproxy: unable to connect to session manager
```

How can I do whatever xeyes or gvim does so that my X connection 'completes' and the keyboard starts working?

ps: My apologies as I know this is a rather specialized subset of linux knowledge, I've tried to do my best in asking the question though, and I have ordered [a book on X](http://amzn.to/Ht9k6m).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest is probably to run `xset q` or `xdpyinfo`, redirecting the output to `/dev/null` so that it doesn't puke on your display.

**EDIT:**

This will run a screensaver, then kill it (change the path and delay as needed):

```
/usr/libexec/mate-screensaver/popsquares & { sleep 0.01 ; kill $! ; }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. installed both `x11-utils` and `x11-session-utils` so i could run those commands but didn't have any luck. running `xeyes` still does the trick though.

Comment: Hrm. I guess you need an application that opens a window and closes after a time. Not `display`... Oh! Maybe a screensaver. Let's see...

Comment: Ok, that's given me some good insight. Apparently it is a problem with XQuartz initializing and not with the remote system. If I switch to XQuartz / X11 and even open a new terminal the clipboard syncing from the remote system starts working. Very strange, thanks for your help.